# How is a part consisting of 4 repeating chords called?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions, terminology

E.g. in the INXS number Near Tear Us Apart there are 4 measures (in the intro/verse) that are repeated continuously (Am7 Fadd9 Dm F). However, in many songs verses/choruses are build up of a repeat of 4 measures.

How is such part of 4 measures called? (probably also could be more, or less for the definition point of view).

I guess it's not a 'riff' as there is not really a melody or typical notes inside, maybe a phrase?

(Actually I'm looking for the Dutch term, but I guess if I can find the English term I can translate/find it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have usually seen this referred to as a **four-chord loop**.

If you are interested in the phenomenon, the youtube channel 12tone has a lot of videos that deal with the theory and application of these loops.

Comment: Thanks, I would expect there would be a dedicated term for it. I make music for about 30 years, but also don't know it, although I never had an official musical training.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not a thing in classical music, so there's no need for a fancy Italian name for it :-) Now that I think of it, I believe jazz musiciancs call repeated chord progressions "vamps", so it would be a "four-chord vamp" (although the term seems to refer not just to chords, but also rhythmic figures etc. - similar to a "riff", I guess).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers It's not really the right term here, but there is in fact a fancy Italian classical-music name for a simple musical element that's repeated throughout the entire work: [ostinato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostinato). (IMO a 4-bar chord progression is a bit too complex to use the word "ostinato"; it would typically be just a simple rhythm pattern or melodic riff.)

Comment: Seems to me that *ostinato* (related to the Dutch word *obstinaat*), or *vamp* are both correct.  The English-language Wikipedia page [Ostinato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostinato) includes "Vamp" as a section.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks for the clarification ... it's not fully repeated through the entire song, but too several parts of it (intro, verse, not chorus).  But I can live with this word, thanks.

Comment: @Theodore - ostinato, to me, seems like a sustained rhythmic pattern 1 or 2 bars long, repeated. 'Vamp till ready' reminds me of the long intros we play, maybe using 4 bars, till the singer can remember the words...